# what hardware drivers does ROS provide?

Tags: ros, hardware

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A list of stacks, packages, or tutorials related to hardware drivers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9033/what-hardware-drivers-does-ros-provide?/) by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8372 on 2011-02-13

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-03-02**:
Is that a quest for the Famous question badge? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS provides several drivers stacks:

- [joystick_drivers](http://ros.org/wiki/joystick_drivers)
- [laser_drivers](http://ros.org/wiki/laser_drivers)
- [camera_drivers](http://ros.org/wiki/camera_drivers)
- [sound_drivers](http://ros.org/wiki/sound_drivers)
- [imu_drivers](http://ros.org/wiki/imu_drivers)
- [kinect](http://ros.org/wiki/kinect)
- [phidgets](http://ros.org/wiki/phidgets)
- [asctec_drivers](http://ros.org/wiki/asctec_drivers)

A list of tutorials can be found at:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/DriverTutorials

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

in addition to the stable hardware stacks, like the ones mention in tfoote's answer, you can also use the [browse software](http://www.ros.org/browse/list.php) feature to search for a particular driver.  The ROS community has wrapped most of the common sensor and actuator drivers that you might need to build a robot.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3